# Как перевести месяцы в годы в таблице Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Всем доброго дня.

Есть таблица типа:

| Пол | Возраст | Опыт(месяцев) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| М | 44 | 73 |
| Ж | 42 | 230 |
| М | 45 | 237 |
| Ж | 27 | 69 |

Нужно значение столбца "Опыт(месяцев)" перевести в годы и месяцы.

Начал делать следующее:

```
exp = np.array([])
for i in list(df['Опыт(месяцев)']):
  years = i // 12
  if i % 12 != 0:
    monts = i % 12
```

Как теперь значения `years` и `monts` поместить в ячейку столбца?

Или может нужен другой подход?

Comment: Покажите в вопросе датасет, который вы хотите получить на выходе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в принципе неверный подход к работе с pandas - зачем делать циклы, если можно использовать векторизированные функции? Например:

```
df["Опыт (лет)"], df["Опыт(месяцев)"] = df["Опыт(месяцев)"].divmod(12)
```

теперь ваш df:

```
  Пол  Возраст  Опыт(месяцев)  Опыт (лет)
0   М       44              1           0
1   Ж       42              2           0
2   М       45              9           0
3   Ж       27              9           0
```

Comment: Решил с помощью цикла, но Ваш метод куда лучше! Спасибо!